# Java Map - как вывести значение более шести

Tags: java, map

Нужно представить класс "User" в виде ассоциативного массива (логин/пароль). И вывести пользователей с длинной пароля более 6. Не понимаю как поставить таки это условие >6 в Java Map.

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.SortedMap;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class Users {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object desiredObject=new Object();

        Integer a = 7;
        desiredObject = a;
        SortedMap<String, Integer> countries = new TreeMap<>();
        countries.put("JDeek", 52351);
        countries.put("CosmisSp", 545111);
        countries.put("Yoda", 1234567);
        for (Map.Entry<?, ?> entry : countries.entrySet())
            if(desiredObject.equals(entry.getValue()))
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue());  
    }


}
for (Map.Entry<?, ?> entry : countries.entrySet())
    if(entry.getValue() >= 1000000) // Если поставить условие такого вида, то в результате ошибка
                                    // The operator >= is undefined for the argument type(s) capture#2-of ?, int
       System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue());
```

}

Comment: `if (entry.getValue() > 999999)` ? но пароль бывает и строкой ведь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Map.Entry надо типизировать, т.е. явно указать типы внутри.

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : countries.entrySet())
     if(entry.getValue() >= 1000000)
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue());  
}
```

---

```
if(entry.getValue() >= 1000000)
```

1000000 - первое семизначное число.

```
if(entry.getValue() > 999999)
```

999999 - последние шестизначное число

Так быстрее чем преобразовывать в строку и брать длину.

Comment: наверное все же 999999 и без равно?

Comment: да согласен, не правильно понял =) больше и равно или просто больше, тут уже на вкус и цвет.

Comment: а если пароль имеет и символьные значения

Comment: @Санаев судя по коду в вопросе - не имеет.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский в задании об этом не сказано, так что вполне возможно, что и символы могут использоваться в пароле

Comment: @Санаев SortedMap<String, Integer> значение может быть только целое число Integer, если бы там могли быть символы, автор бы просто взял String.length()

Comment: @Виктор нет вопросов, думал String стоит

Comment: Дело в том, что я пытался ставить такое условие, но выбило ошибку рода
" The operator >= is undefined for the argument type(s) capture#2-of ?, int "

Comment: надо типизировать Map.Entry дополнил в ответе.

Comment: Действительно, помогло